# Ajuda com sistema de login

Tags: php, array, login, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

Estou montando um sistema de login. Mas não consigo fazer a validação da senha digitada.

Quando tento desta forma ele acusa login/senha errado. Mas ja me certifiquei, o login e senha estao corretos:

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

// resgata dados digitados no formulario
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email']: '';
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha']: '';

// Verifica se os campos do form nao estao vazios
if(empty($email) || empty($senha)){
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Infome Email e senha.');window.location.href='../login.php';</script>";
    exit;
}

// Comando no banco de dados
$pdo = db_connect();    // Abre conexão com o banco

$sql = "SELECT id, nome FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha";
// Cria query

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);    // Prepare da query

$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue(':senha', $senha);
// Atribui valor do campo email no valor email da query

$stmt->execute();   // Execute na query

$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   // Cria array associativo

if(count($arr) <= 0) {  // Verifica se a busca trouxe retorno
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha inválido!');window.location.href='../login.php';</script>";
    exit;
}

    // Pega o primeiro usuario
    $user = $arr[0];

    // Inicia a sessão
    session_start();

    // Definir os dados persistindo entre paginas
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['nome'];

    header('Location: ../index.php');
```

Quando dou `var_dump($arr);` ele me retorna um array vazio, por isso ele não faz o login.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Grato!

======= DEBUG =======

Código atual: http://pastebin.com/QPa2555i

Email: admin@admin.com   |   Senha: 123456

Usuario certo, senha errada:
Result: acusa Senha errada

Usuario certo, senha certa:
Result: acusa senha errada também

Usuario errado, senha certa:
Result: acusa usuário não encontrado

Usuario errado, senha errada:
Result: acusa usuario não encontrado também

Com usuario e senha corretos, usando var_dump($senha) e var_dump($arr[0]['senha'])

[image: Debug com EMAIL e SENHA corretos!]

Agora com a linha `if (!password_verify($senha, $arr[0]['senha'])) {` antes estava sem o `!`

[image: Debug]

Comment: A senha não está convertida no BD né?

Comment: A senha no banco esta criptografada, usei o password_hash para criptografar

Comment: Esse é o caso que a gente tem que resolver então: `usuário certo, senha certa: Result: acusa senha errada também`

Answer (score 0):

**Edição**

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php';

// Dados do formulário
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

// Verifica se os campos estão vazios: usuário OU senha
if (empty($email) OR empty($senha)) {
    // Se sim, mostra mensagem e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
    echo 'Preencha os campos';
    header('Location: ../index.php');
}

// Cria objeto PDO: conexão com o banco de dados
$pdo = db_connect();

$sql = "select id, nome, senha from usuarios where email = :email";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));

$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);

$stmt->execute();

// Conta o número de linhas retornadas
$contar = $stmt->rowCount();

// Verifica se existe apenas um registro com o login informado: login unico
if ($contar == 1) {
    // Se sim, retorna os dados do banco de dados
    $arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Compara o hash de senha do banco de dados, com o hash da senha informada pelo usuário
    if (password_verify($senha, $arr[0]['senha'])) {
        echo 'Bem-vindo ao sistema...';
    } else {
        echo 'Senha errada';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Usuário não encontrado';
}
```

Verifica se a senha está encriptada no banco de dados (hash da senha) e qual o algoritmo (sha1, md5 etc) e compare os hash se for o caso:

```
$hashDaSenha = password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt->bindValue(':senha', $hashDaSenha));
```

Se esse não for o caso, tente usar [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php) no lugar de *count()*;

```
// Usando PDO::rowCount()

if($stmt->rowCount() <= 0) { 
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha inválido!');window.location.href='../login.php';</script>";
    exit;
}
```

No prepare(), use o seguinte:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
```